# How do the French people typically say, 'I already have a good feeling about them'?

Tags: anglais, oral

'Sorry, it’s not the time for my doom and gloom. I have to be honest, I won’t pretend to know exactly what those new attractions are, but I already have a good feeling about them.'

I was watching an American TV drama program on Netflix and I remember hearing a line like above. I want to find out if there exists French expressions resembling 'I already have a good feeling about them'. Its meaning is like saying that even though one can't be certain of its success, from the look of things, I have a good hunch that it will succeed.

Is 'J'ai une bonne impression envers leurs succès' well understood by the French people?

Comment: **In what context are they discussing attractions**? Attractions are what you find at fairs.The entire thing hinges on the word attractions. Ferris wheels and cyclones? Or what?

Answer (score 5):

I'd rather go for something like:

"Pour être honnête, je ne vais pas prétendre savoir exactement ce que sont ces nouvelles attractions, mais... :

- j'ai déjà un bon a priori
- j'ai un bon pressentiment
- je le sens bien  (as explained in comments, it's more informal)
- je suis déjà confiant dans leur succès
- je suis déjà optimiste quant à la réussite (some comments explained it would be an improper use of réussite, I have to check this point, I'll update this line accordingly)

You can replace “dans” and “quant à” in the previous examples.

Comment: in your second sentence it is 'leur réussite'

Comment: BTW your first two propositions are correct only if the person who is speaking thinks about the commercial success of the attractions. Which is not what I thought about at first when I read the line, I was more thinking about a person thinking to go to an amusement park in order to experiment new attractions

Comment: @Aldian even after your remark I still understand it as a commercial success of the attractions. About "réussite", personnally I apply it only to persons, to not machines, but rather to those who exploits those attractions: so I'd say simply "la réussite".

Comment: An additional suggestion, but more colloquial:  *je le sens bien*.

Comment: @Greg good idea! I use it often.

Comment: @StephaneRolland You just don't say "la réussite". It's like saying "I am confident in the success" => the success of what?. If you want to keep "la", you have to add something, for example "quant à la réussite des attractions" or "quand à la réussite de l'évènement". You can check it on the cntrtl https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%A9ussite it is always "la réussite de.." or "la réussite que..", you never have "la réussite." alone at the end of the phrase. It is  grammatically correct, it kind of makes sense, but french people just don't say this

Comment: @Aldian maybe you don't, but I do say that. When cheering for exemple, I can say "A la réussite!" or "A ta réussite!". If that is incorrect French, then I have a bad habit that I have been accustomed to for a long long time, it is possible.

Comment: @StephaneRolland "A ta réussite!" is like my suggestion "A leur réussite". It indicates by itself who is expected to succeed. As for "A la réussite!" it is kind of special since this is imperative form. I would not count it as a valid example

Comment: @Aldian I have edited and put a comment about this line, I'll check that point later. In case your are true, which is possible, I'll either edit or remove that line.

Comment: @Aldrian I've also seached linguee.fr for some other examples, and statistics are totally on your side. I just found this one sentence that may go in my direction: "autre caractéristique que les deux gestionnaires considèrent comme un élément essentiel de la réussite : la conviction."  It implies an implicit subject of the "réussite". What do you think ?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Stephane Rolland propositions, you can also say *"J'ai un bon pressentiment"*, which has the notion of feeling, intuition.

Answer (score 1):

I am French, and I would translate like this:

"*Désolé, je n'ai pas envie de broyer du noir. Pour être honnête, je ne sais pas exactement en quoi consistent ces nouvelles attractions, mais j'ai déjà un bon a priori*"

Not easy to be more accurate without more context as the first part of the phrase depends a lot on what it is answering to. As for the last part, one could also translate "*mais je les sens bien*", which is a bit more familiar in term of language level

Answer (score 1):

In Québecois French, a colloquial way to say this is, "J'ai un bon feeling sur ça." (whether referring to one or more things)

Comment: This "Québécois French" expression is quite common in France too.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use this translation into French;

- Désolé, ce n'est pas le moment d'être pessimiste. Il faut que je reste franc, je ne vais pas prétendre savoir exactement ce que sont ces attractions **mais l'impression que j'en ai déjà est bonne**.

On peut cependant dire « **mais j'en ai déjà une bonne impression.** » (peut-être un peu moins emphatique)

Comment: to have a good feeling about something is indeed: avoir (une) bonne impression de quelque chose

Answer (score 0):

The idea of a hunch that you think is true you can translate with *mon petit doigt me dit*, you can also use the expression when you know something to be true but you don't want to say how you got the information:

> - A vrai dire, je connais pas les nouveaux manèges, mais mon petit doigt me dit qu'ils sont pas mal.